# CSS float left image column responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have 3 columns using float.

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: auto">
<div style="float: left; width: 5%"> col1 </div>
<div style="float: left; width: auto"> col2 IMAGE in pixels </div>
<div style="float: left; width: 60%"> col3 content </div>
</div>
```

I need a full width however column 2 image width that can be set in pixels e.g. 200px
and column 3 to fill in 100%

Is it possible to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

this also should work:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DDGsz/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wpr">
<div class="col1"> col1 </div>
<div class="col2"><img style="width:400px;" src="http://www.connox.de/m/100030/139194/media/Chikuno-Life/Chikuno-Cube/chikuno-cube-frei-440x440.jpg"></div>
<div class="col3"> col3 content </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wpr{width: 100%; margin: auto, display:inline-block;}
.col1{float: left; width: 5%; height:100%; background:silver;}
.col2{float: left; display:inline; width: auto; }
.col3{display:table-cell; wideth:auto; height:100%; background:red;}
```

the width property in  is only to test it now it also word with more content in col3

Comment: Hi, if there is a long content on 3'rd column the content goes under the column 2 so it does not work

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, the only thing, is it possible to have last column width: 100%, now if the content i shorter all elements goes to the max width of the longest element e.g. can't do flaot right on elements for that column

Comment: Timo, can you please check my last question?

Comment: i only find a solution with one more div around col3 i hope this is a possible solution for you : http://jsfiddle.net/DDGsz/3/

Answer (score 0):

One way would be like this

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/2awZU/7/)**

First column: Use `float:left` and `width:5%`;

Second column: Fixed width: 200px with `float:left`

Third Column: `overflow:hidden` (or overflow: auto) to fill remaining width

### Markup:

```
<div class="wpr">
    <div class="col1"> col1 </div>
    <div class="col2"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="col3"> col3 content </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wpr
{
    width: 100%;
}
.col1
{
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
}
.col2
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.col3
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: I need to insert the image dynamically with php so the background won't work

Answer (score 0):

dirty but I guess it should cause your problem:

`<script>
    window.onload = window.onresize = function(event)
    {
        var wrapper = (document.getElementById('100% WIDTH ELEMENTS ID')[0].offsetWidth);

        document.getElementById('ID WITH MISSING WIDTH').style.width = 100/wrapper-"PRESET IMG WIDTH";
    }
</script>`